# Can I use Instagram API to get other users bio?

Tags: python, html, instagram

I'm a bit confused about the capabilities of the instagram basic display api...

I want to create a web app where the users put a link in their instagram bio in order to validate their account. I want my web app to check this through the instagram api.

Is this something that is possible and legal/allowed?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `https://www.instagram.com/<name>/?__a=1` to get some info about a user

```py
import requests

user = "linustech"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': ''
}


r = requests.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{user}/?__a=1", headers=headers)
userinfo = r.json()["graphql"]

bio = userinfo["user"]["biography"]


print(bio)
# Official Instagram account for Linus Tech Tips. Run by the entire LMG team. Get 20% off @manscaped at ↙
```

Instagrams [robots.txt](https://www.instagram.com/robots.txt) states that search engine crawlers can't use any URL with `__a=1`. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro)

Comment: So is this an API endpoint for instagram itself?

Comment: Is it popular to use this for your applications?

Comment: @Sven have you used this since? I need it for my server and idk if its a viable endpoint
boop, ping

Comment: @Nikola-Milovic unfortunately I don't think that it is a good solution...

Comment: @Sven yeah I am aware, unfortunately the facebook dev community and facebook in general is godawful. Havent had the displeasure of working on something more horrific than facebook apis. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69341896/how-to-add-instagram-bio-verification-to-my-app

Comment: I want to update my bio using Instagram api. is it possible as I'm not able to find any endpoint for the same?